# how to initialize list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I was using list comprehension in Python. But my program behaves differently based on the way how I initialize the variable

1. Works as expected if am using below piece of code
   `temp = [[-1 for y in range(k + 1)] for x in range(n + 1)]`
2. It behaves strange if am using below code
   `temp = [[-1]*(k+1)]*(n + 1)`

what is the difference between both the ways of initializing the variable

Comment: Only one of those is a listcomp.  The other is just a multiplied literal.

Comment: The outputs are the same. What kind of "different behaviour" do you see?

Comment: The outputs are not the same since the same list reference is repeated n+1 times in example 2.